# UWP app sign in to Facebook works on phone, but not on desktop

Tags: facebook, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have UWP app that uses Sign In to Facebook. I use library winsdkfb.

The app successfully signs in when I run it on the phone, but on desktop it gives me "Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again."

Considering that the code is exactly the same, don't even know what to try now.

For Valid OAuth redirect URIs I tried:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
and 
https://www.facebook.com

Result is the same, works on the phone, but not on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Hah!

I had to enable setting "Web OAuth Login", I had it set to "No", and apparently it was good enough for Windows 10 Mobile, but not for Windows 10 Desktop. After I changed it to "Yes", it helped.